# How can i group the joining table using ci jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

[image: This is the code in my index to display the output]
[image: please click here to view the image]
Here is my code in model: please help me to fix that thankyou in advance.
i want is to join under of the no. 5 id look at the image for the reference.

```
 public function showallcoddislist(){
            $company_id  = $this->input->get('company_id');
            $location_id = $this->input->get('location_id');
            $cod_id = $this->input->get('id');

            $this->db->distinct('A.cod_disob_id');
            $this->db->select('A.cod_disob_id,A.disob_title,B.disob,B.punish,B.num_days,B.offense,B.pun_id');       
            $this->db->order_by('A.cod_disob_id', 'asc');
            $this->db->where(array(
                        'A.company_id' => $company_id,
                        'A.location_id' => $location_id,
                        'A.cod_id' => $cod_id
                ));
            $this->db->join("cod_disob_punish B","B.cod_disob_id = A.cod_disob_id","left outer");

            $query = $this->db->get('cod_disobedience A');

            if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->result();
            }else{
                return false;
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function showallcoddislist(){
        $company_id  = $this->input->get('company_id');
        $location_id = $this->input->get('location_id');
        $cod_id = $this->input->get('id');

        $this->db->distinct('A.cod_disob_id');
        $this->db->select('A.cod_disob_id,MAX(A.cod_disob_id) as cod_disob_id,A.disob_title,B.disob,B.punish,B.num_days,B.offense,B.pun_id');       
        $this->db->order_by('A.cod_disob_id', 'asc');
        $this->db->where(array(
                    'A.company_id' => $company_id,
                    'A.location_id' => $location_id,
                    'A.cod_id' => $cod_id
            ));
        $this->db->join("cod_disob_punish B","B.cod_disob_id = A.cod_disob_id","left outer");
        $this->db->groupBy(['cod_disob_id'])
        $query = $this->db->get('cod_disobedience A');

        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
        }else{
            return false;
        }

}
```

Comment: MAX(A.cod_disob_id) as cod_disob_id

$this->db->group_by(['cod_disob_id']);

not working.. anything suggestion sir? thankyou in advance

Comment: try GROUP_CONCAT  like $query->select('cod_disob_id, GROUP_CONCAT(A.disob_title) as disob_title,GROUP_CONCAT(B.disob) as disob')

Comment: i add group_by and the result is only one idof 5Disobedience 5 may only problem is the under of this id only one will apear

Comment: group_by is not needed when you use GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: yes i remove group_by when i try concat.. i change my mind i seperate the the list of punishment in other modal